# How to make PM2 start Angular Universal?

Tags: angular, pm2, angular-universal

I deployed my Angular Universal app to the production server. I run it with PM2 and it works. However, it doesn't run the Universal side of the app. When I view the page source of the web page I don't see the content, but the app-root tag.

It's as if PM2 launched regular Angular by doing 'ng serve', instead of doing 'npm run serve:ssr' for Angular Universal.

This is (part of) my package.json with the scripts. Do I have to put 'npm run serve:ssr' in here somewhere so this command is run when I call 'PM2 start server.js'?

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node server",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run AppName:server:production --bundleDependencies all"
  }
```

**Update**

Because I was getting a 403 error I had the web host set the document root of Apache to the browser folder, because that's where the index.html is located. Is that what may be causing a problem that it won't load the Universal side of the app? Because it's now not seeing the server folder? This is what my folder structure looks like:

```
domains
    - appname.com
        - public_html
            - browser (=> this is the document root)
                - index.html
                - .htaccess
                - other files...
            - server
            - server.js
            - package.json
```

And my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d

    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you've created your bundles and deployed everything on your webserver, you can just make pm2 start your server.js file

Here is the `pm2config.json` file that we use in our project

```
{
  "apps": [
       {
    "name": "universalService",
    "script": "./dist/server.js",
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "",
      "watch": false
    },
    "env_production": {
      "NODE_ENV": "production"
    },


    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I did start the server.js file with pm2, however it's not showing the content in page source. Also weird, when I stop pm2, empty cache or open website in cognito browser it still works... How is that even possible? Is it still cached somewhere?

Comment: I think that's because your rule redirecting  traffic to angular universal does not work I think. The above answer is just to start universal using pm2, but you need to configure Apache with proper rules

Comment: I added my .htaccess redirect in my question. I know this works because it fixed the 404 when I refresh the page. I had my web host configure the httpd.conf file because I'm not a root user on the server. They added a proxy to port 4000 where my app is running and they set the document root to the browser folder. Could you maybe share your Apache configuration if you have it?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this tutorial: https://tecadmin.net/how-to-run-angular-app-with-pm2/

---

After I built and deployed it to my Nginx server I installed pm2.
Checked my scripts (in package.json) for:

`"serve:ssr": "node dist/ModernaMediaAngular/server/main.js"`

located to the path

```
../dist/ModernaMediaAngular/server/main.js
```

in my nginx server and used the command:

```
pm2 start "node dist/ModernaMediaAngular/server/main.js" --name "ModernaMedia"
```